# Prove/Disprove that if $G$ is the group with a unique element $x$ of order $2$, then $Z(G)$ has a unique Sylow-$2$ subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Q. Let $G$ be the group with a unique element $x$ of order $2$, then which of the following is/are always true

(A) $x \in Z(G),$ the center of $G$

(B) $Z(G)$ has a unique sylow-2 subgroup

(C) $Z(G)$ is not simple

(D) $G$ is a simple group

My attempt:

A. Its clear that $gxg^{-1}=x$ for all $g \in G$, which gives $x \in Z(G).$

C, D. $G$ and $Z(G)$ are need not be simple if they have order $\geq 3$.

Doubt: I know that order of $Z(G)$ is even and thereby $Z(G)$ has a Sylow-2 subgroup, but how to confirm it is of order $2$ rather than $2^2,...$? Is it true the option B?

Comment: I do not understand your doubt. Why do you expect the Sylow-2-subgroup of $Z(G)$ to be order $2$? After all $G$ might be cyclic of order $4$ for all we are given.  But putting that aside how many Sylow-2-subgroups does any abelian group have?

Comment: Your reasoning for C and D is not entirely correct. You are right that $\{e,x\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and of $Z(G)$, but this does not imply straight away that $Z(G)$ is nonsimple since it may occur that $Z(G) = \{e,x\}$. You need an example where $\{e,x\}$ is properly contained in the center. Likewise, there's the same issue with D.

Comment: $A,B$ are definitely true    Remember the center is always abelian.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$A,B$ are true. Remember the center of a group is abelian.

$\Bbb Z_2$ shows that $C$ is false.

$\Bbb Z_6$ shows $D$ is false.

Comment: But there are also examples of groups $G$ for which C and D are true, so the answer should be that it depends on $G$. (I expect your answer is the intended answer, but the question is seriously badly worded.)

Comment: @hawaiianearringgroup   How can I say Abelian groups with even order always have unique Sylow-2 subgroup?

Comment: @DerekHolt I've tried to improve the question, thank you.

Comment: @Riaz Easier: state (or prove, it is pretty easy with Sylow theorems) that for a prime $\;p\;$ the exists a unique $\;p\,$-Sylow subgroup iff it is a normal subgroup. With this you have have, among others, for abelian groups.

Comment: @DonAntonio But the $p-$Sylow subgroup need not be of order $p$, right? Here, my doubt is 'why the normal subgroup $\{0,x\}$ becomes the unique $2-$Sylow subgroup?, what is the logical impossibility of $2-$Sylow subgroup with order $2^k$ for some $k>1$? thanks in advance.

Comment: No.  The reason is that the Sylow subgroups in abelian groups are always unique. The order could be any power of $2$.  We know that there's a Sylow-$2$ because of an element of order $2$.

Comment: @hawaiianearringgroup How to justify $2^k,~k(>1) \in \Bbb N$ doesn't divide $|G|$? any contradiction? thanks.

Comment: The existence of an element of order $2$ implies that the group has even order.  Since it's in the center,  so does the center.   Since the center has even order,  it has a Sylow-$2$ subgroup.   The order will be the maximum power of $2$ that divides the group order.   But the center is abelian.   So that Sylow subgroup is unique.

Comment: @hawaiianearringgroup Are you telling that the only subgroup of $Z(G)$ having order $2^k$, for some $k \in \Bbb N$ is $\{0,x\}$?

Comment: @hawaiianearringgroup I know that there is no subgroup of order $2$ other than $\{0,x\}$, but how does it imply there is no subgroups of order $2^2,2^3,...$ for $Z(G)$? thanks.

Comment: @Riaz None of the people making comments has said at any point that $Z(G)$ can have no subgroup of order $2^k$ for $k>1$. The claim is that any abelian group whatsoever has a unique Sylow $p$-subgroup for any prime $p$ dividing its order. So that applies to $Z(G)$ in this case.